# Roots of an equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$

Tags: field-theory, roots

> In the field $\mathbb{Z_{19}}$, consider the equation $x^2+\bar{5}x-\bar{7}$. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the roots of the equation. If the polynomial $P(x) = x^2+\bar{5}-\bar{7}$ is *reducible*, then the roots belong to $\mathbb{Z_{19}}$. If it is *irreducible*, then they belong in the Galois field $F = GF(19,P(x))$. Compute $r_1^2 + r_2^2$.

This is what I'm working on. In the class of $\mathbb{Z_{19}}$, we have the elements ${\bar 0,\bar 1,\bar 2,\bar 3,\bar 4...\bar {16},\bar {17},\bar {18}}$. So basically, I believe I have to find two solutions to the polynomial $P(x) = x^2+\bar{5}x-\bar{7}$. Or, in other words, $ x^2+\bar{5}x-\bar{7} \equiv 0$ (mod $19)$. I could use the trial and error method, but for future problems, what if I work with a different field with more elements in its class, such as $\mathbb{Z_{29}}$ for example? There must be an efficient way of finding these roots without doing the trail and error approach.

Comment: It's actually $r_1 + r_2 = -5$.

Comment: Hang on, are you sure you wrote down your numbers correctly? This equation does _not_ have roots!!!

Comment: One way to see that the equation does not have roots is to complete the square, and write the equation as $(x + 12)^2 = -1$. So the equation has roots iff $-1$ is a quadratic residue. But since $\mathbb Z_{19}^{\times}$ is cyclic of order 18, the element $-1$ is the ninth power of the generator of $\mathbb Z_{19}^{\times}$. Since nine is odd, it is clear that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: The equation is written down correctly. Let me check again.

Comment: But it doesn't have roots! I just tested all nineteen possible values of $x$ on a spreadsheet and none of them work...

Comment: That's interesting. Yes the equation is written down correctly.

Comment: And it's definitely mod 19?

Comment: Yes. I will post a pic of it.

Comment: Are you supposed to consider an extension field that contains the roots?

Comment: Oh perhaps this edit will help out.

Comment: Hold on I will write down the entire question down.

Comment: Okay, so the roots belong to an extension field! In fact, they belong to the finite field of size $19^2$. Even so, our strategy with $r_1 + r_2$ and $r_1 r_2$ will work. :)

Comment: Ah good thing I wrote the entire question then! But it's good to double check :) Appreciate the help Kenny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited to incorporate some comments made after question was clarified.)

Notice that if $r_1 $ and $r_2$ are the two roots of the quadratic in a splitting field, then
$$ (x - r_1)(x - r_2) = x^2 + \bar 5 x - \bar 7.$$

Therefore,
$$ r_1 + r_2 = - \bar 5, \ \ \ \ \ r_1 r_2 = - \bar 7.$$

From here, we have
$$ r_1^2 + r_2^2 = (r_1 + r_2)^2 - 2r_1 r_2 = (- \bar 5)^2 - 2 ( - \bar 7) = \bar 1 \in \mathbb Z_{19}.$$

---

In fact, the quadratic does not split in $\mathbb Z_{19}$. One easy way to see this is to complete the square, i.e. write it as $(x + \overline{12})^2 + \bar 1$. Now note that $- \bar 1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $19$, since $-1$ is the ninth power of the generator of the group of units mod $19$, and nine is odd. So the splitting field for the quadratic is the finite field of order $19^2$, and the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ live in this splitting field.

Comment: Is it clear that it always has two roots if not will this still work?

Comment: Wait, how is $r_1 + r_2 = -\bar{5}$?

Comment: Ahh nevermind, you're right. happymath I believe you meant to say $r_1 + r_2 = -\bar{5}$, not $\bar{5}$

Comment: Well, I assumed we were told that the quadratic has two roots! Of course, if it doesn't, then this wouldn't work.

Comment: Would it help if we knew $r_1 - r_2$?

Comment: Ahh is it just a matter of squaring both sides of $r_1 + r_2 = -\bar{5}$, same with the RHS and we do s simple substitution?

Comment: No, $(r_1 + r_2)^2 - 2(r_1 r_2) = r_1^2 + r_2^2$.

Comment: I got $\bar{20}$ = $r_1^2 + r_2^2$.

Comment: Oh I see what you did. On your previous comment, did you just add the term $-2(r_1r_2)$ to balance out the equation?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Now it's super clear.

Answer (score 0):

Bhaskara's formula works, in the sense that a solution exists if and only if $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ exists in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$. In other words, if and only if $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue modulo $19$. Do you think you can take it from here?